# How to place embedded link in videos?

Tags: video, quicktime, after-effects

I am trying to place an embedded link in offline video. Is there any solution to do that? I tried with QuickTime software but it's not helping me. Is there any software to put embedded links in videos?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: (1) StackOverflow is about **programming** questions. Maybe use your same account to ask at : **https://video.stackexchange.com/** since that community handles video software.  (2) About _"I tried with QuickTime software but it's not helping me"_ explain what you've tried & how it's not working (what is expected result?). Maybe it's just wrong step? (3) I haven't seen a `.MOV` video open a (web) link in last 15 years (I remember the pop-ups during Windows 98 era). Is such (insecure) feature still supported in 2017? (4) If watched offline (no internet) then why care about inserting a web link?

Answer (score 0):

You can use two div tags.

Css code:

```
.div1{height:30px; width:100%; background:#fff; position:relative; z-index:1;}.div2{height:30px; width:100%; background:#f00; position:absolute; top:0px; left:0; z-index:2;}
```

Html Code:

```
<div class="div1"><div class="div2"></div></div>
```

div2 will completely cover div1.

This is a thinking.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I know that was (and still might be) able to do that is Quicktime Pro 7.x.x See:

- [Creating a Clickable Web Link | Creating Interactive Movies with QuickTime Pro](http://www.peachpit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=758432&seqNum=3)
- [Download - QuickTime Player 7.6.6 for Mac OS X v10.6.3 or newer](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL923)
- [Authoring Wired Media (QuickTime Developer Series)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1558607463)

Alternatives are:

- Using Flash (but that means you will need the Flashplayer on that machine)
- Using HTML5 (then you need a browser)